# Multi-class text classification where classification depends on other columns beside text column

Tags: python, nlp

I want to do text classification in Python where I have a df with 3 columns: scenario, text and label. The label depends on the column text but also on the column scenario. There are 6 different scenarios.

Would it be correct to make a new column where I would merge columns scenario and text into one string and then do the tokenization and the rest of the model training with just this new column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how you would be merging the two. Simply concatenating might not be the best idea. It might be good to introduce a special token between the two strings, like the [SEP] (or any other token) during the training and the inference so that it becomes easier for the model to understand the pattern.

You can either make a new column with this merged string and use it for your training, or merge the text from the two column in your data loader. The first option is the easier one.

If you are interested in playing around with the model, you can also try encoding the text from the first column using an encoder like bert, then encoding the text from the second column and concatenating the two vectors and feeding it two the classifier head.

All that said, the simple approach of creating a third column with the two texts concatenated with a separator should work fine.

Comment: thank you. i merged it and used [SEP] and got pretty decent accuracy

Comment: great, if the answer works for you, please mark it as the accepted answer. That way others with similar question can also benefit from your experiments